Receive licensing error wordpress installation
I get this // http://civicrm.org/licensing // instead of the admin page in wordpress, with Wordpress 6.5.2 and CiviCRM up to date.
I have tried to update with the link "http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1" but nothing is showing.
I have also tried to install CiviCRM several times but it isn't working.
Please advise, than you!

Not an answer, but I found this thread while searching for a hint to my issue which seems very similar to this topic.
For my situation, I have WordPress 6.5.4 and attempted to install CiviCRM version 5.74.1. I initially "activated" the Civi plugin and this brought up the "CiviCRM Installer" page where I clicked on the "Install CiviCRM" button. Then that screen immediately went blank but I waited one hour before giving up and logging back into WordPress. Then I noticed the menu item changed to "CiviCRM" (which sounded promising), but clicking on the "CiviCRM" submenu, I was greeted by a page that simply displays: "// http://civicrm.org/licensing //".
It was strange not seeing ANY reports, good or bad. Like you, I also tried several times with the same odd results. I am wondering if there has been any progress on this topic that might help me.
I see this topic is only one month old, so I figured I would piggyback on this topic instead of creating a separate new one. Thanks!
=========================================
Update: I fixed my issue - I found a log under my HOME directory that has the following report:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "IntlDateFormatter" not found
in
/home/arliedtke/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Date.php:271

For me, I was missing the (required) PHP INTL package. CiviCRM is working as expected after installing that package. Hope this helps your situation.

For help in installing the intl php extension ... a nice script was created to add any extension, including intl, to a Docker php container: https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer. This is the excerpt from my php.dockerfile that adds in intl, gd, exif, opcache. Note the opcache extension signifcantly increased performance for my case as CiviCRM has more resource requirements than plain vanilla Wordpress.
`
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine
...
// need intl php extension for CiviCRM, gd & exif for WP plugins on my website, opcache for performance
RUN ( curl -sSLf https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions -o - || echo 'return 1' ) | sh -s
gd exif intl opcache
`
